# Find acceleration using Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string

[image: system]

I was trying to find acceleration of $m_3$ using Lagrangian. Without speaking a lot I am just starting to show my equations.

$$L=T-U$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}m_1\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}m_3\dot{x}^2-m_1gx-m_2g(l-x)$$
I didn't write potential energy of $m_3$ cause both rope/string have same length. When they are pulling that object potential energy of $m_3$ will be constant. And when using Euler form then it will be gone hence I am not going to write potential energy of $m_3$. It seems wrong to me. Although I am just going to do whatever I said.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}=m_1\ddot{x}+m_2\ddot{x}+m_3\ddot{x}$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=-m_1g+m_2g$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$$
$$\Rightarrow m_1\ddot{x}+m_2\ddot{x}+m_3\ddot{x}=g(m_2-m_1) $$
$$\Rightarrow\ddot{x}=g\frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1+m_2+m_3}$$

The equation is approximately correct. When looking at answer (which was done Newtonian way) I saw that $$a=g\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2+m_3}$$

Hence the mistake is on the red marked variable $$\ddot{x}=g\frac{\color{red}{m_2-m_1}}{m_1+m_2+m_3}$$ If I use the equation than I get same value but negative. That's the error.

Comment: What is $x$? Failure to define coordinates and variables always leads to silly errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you wrote $U=m_1gx + m_2g(l-x) \rightarrow \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=-m_1g+m_2g$.

From the definition of $U$ think about how the potential would change as the system moved through various $x$. As $x$ gets large, the potential from $m_1$ gets larger, and the potential from $m_2$ gets smaller (or more negative). And so based on your definition of $x$ the positive references direction is to the *right*, at least that is how you have written your potential.

Whereas it seems in the Newtonian case you assumed the positive reference direction to be to the *left*. It should be noted that both answers could very well be valid if you properly give the direction; in other words $5\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ to the left is the same thing as $-5\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ to the right.

If you want the reference direction of $x$ to match simply evaluate $U=m_2gx + m_1g(l-x)$ and you're good to go!